# Add delimiter in string before a certain pattern in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of certain words
`["area", "building", "street no", "floor"]`

If in a string anyone of the following word is succeeded by colon(:), I need to add a delimiter(preferably comma) before that word.
 For example:

`sample_input = "area : al mansorah street no    : 30 building : xyz tower floor: 3rd"`

`expected_output = "area: al mansorah, street no: 30, building: xyz tower, floor: 3rd"`

This is my current implementation:

```
        sentence= "area : al mansorah street no    : 30 building : 6 floor : 3rd"
        words = ["area", "building", "street no", "floor"]
        for x in words:
            regex = re.escape(x) + r"\s+:"
            rep_str = ", " + x + ":"
            sentence = re.sub(regex, rep_str, sentence)
```

This is working but it's quite inefficient because I've more than hundreds such words to check.
It's not covering edge cases as well, like don't add delimiter if it is first word and don't add delimiter if it's already there.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `sentence = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)({})\s+:'.format( '|'.join(map(re.escape, words)) ), r'\1:', sentence)` instead of the whole `for x in words:....`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you please explain what exactly `(?<!\S)` is doing here?

Comment: It is a whitespace boundary. Either whitespace before the match should exist, or start of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're probably looking for is `([^,\s])(\s+(?:your|words|here)\s*:)` since it fits nicely into python and can grow dynamically. Instead of using a for loop to run this regex hundreds of times, you can use a for loop to *build* a regex hundreds of words long, and then run it one time.

- `([^\s,])` Capture a non-comma, non-whitespace character - if there's already a comma, or this is the first word in the line, it'll be ignored.
- `(\s+(?:your|words|here)\s*:)` Capture one or more whitespace characters, followed by any of your words in the list, and ending with a colon.

[Regex demo!](https://regex101.com/r/bF8LaH/3/)

```py
#the first part of the string
rex_str = "([^,\s])(\s+(?:"
#the first word
rex_str += words[0]

#get the rest of the words into the non capture group
for i in range(1, len(words)):
  rex_str += "|"
  rex_str += words[i]

#close the regex
rex_str += ")\s*:)"

#add a comma between the first and second capture groups
sentence = re.sub(rex_str, "\g<1>,\g<2>", sentence)
```

[Python demo!](https://repl.it/repls/DeterminedGrimyAdministration)

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer.
But I need to add delimiter only if the given list of words is succeeded by a colon.
This is adding comma even if there is no colon after the word.


`"area : al mansorah street no    : 30 building 6 floor : 3rd"`

Such cases are failing here, as I don't need comma before builiding.

Comment: This is working fine, but only issue is it's not able to maintain formatting.
`"area   : al mansorah street no     : 30 building : 6 floor  : 3rd"`
this should be formatted like `"area: al mansorah, street no: 30, building: 6, floor : 3rd"`
Everything else is perfectly fine, hence I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Thank you for adding Regex demo, as it really helped me to understand the regex completely.

Answer (score 1):

With the following line you almost get what you want:

```
sentence= "area : al mansorah street no    : 30 building : 6 floor : 3rd"
words = ["area", "building", "street no", "floor"]

sentence = re.sub(r"(?<!^)\s*({})\s*:".format('|'.join(words)), ", \\1:", sentence)

sentence
'area : al mansorah, street no: 30, building: 6, floor: 3rd'
```

The only thing that is not formatted properly is the first word.
What I would do, in that case, is add a specific case for the first word as well:

```
# format words when they are the first word in the sentence
sentence = re.sub(r"^\s*({})\s*:".format('|'.join(words)), "\\1:", sentence)

# format words when they are not the first word in the sentence
sentence = re.sub(r"(?<!^)\s*({})\s*:".format('|'.join(words)), ", \\1:", sentence)
```

and the result is:

```
sentence = "area : al mansorah street no : 30, building : 6, floor : 3rd"
words = ["area", "building", "street no", "floor"]

# format words when they are the first word in the sentence
sentence = re.sub(r"^[\s,]*({})\s*:".format('|'.join(words)), "\\1:", sentence)

# format words when they are not the first word in the sentence
sentence = re.sub(r"(?<!^)[\s,]*({})\s*:".format('|'.join(words)), ", \\1:", sentence)

sentence
'area: al mansorah, street no: 30, building: 6, floor: 3rd'
```

[Edit] I changed the regex so that it would not fail for cases where the delimiter is already there.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and it's working.
but it's not covering the case when the delimiter is already present.
In case of existing delimiter, it should add the delimiter.

Comment: Please, share an example that is failing. :) It would be easier to help. Thanks!

Comment: `"area : al mansorah, street no    : 30, building : 6, floor : 3rd"`
This will fail here, as it would add extra delimiter which is already there.
expected_output : `"area: al mansorah, street no: 30, building: 6, floor: 3rd"`

Comment: Cool. I edited the answer and changed the regex so that it would not fail for cases where the delimiter is already there.